# Distinguishing between NicEditor DIVs on one page

Tags: jquery, nicedit

I'm having trouble with Jquery. I think this is just a matter of me being a novice, but I've put a lot of research in, tried some complex suggestions and nothing seems to work. I've got a page with two nicEdit text areas. I want to add discreet onkeyup functions for each of them, but nicEdit wipes their IDs so I can't seem to treat them independently via ID. Is there another way?

```
new nicEditor({buttonList : ['link', 'unlink']}).panelInstance('area1');
new nicEditor({buttonList : ['link', 'unlink']}).panelInstance('area2');

$("div.nicEdit-main").keyup(function () {
    alert('first textarea');
});

$("div.nicEdit-main").keyup(function () {
   alert('second textarea');
});
```

I'm sure this is a simple one, but it's been eluding me for awhile. Thanks for your help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not that familiar with niceedit, but if you know the order of them on a page you could do:

```
$("div.nicEdit-main:eq(0)").keyup(function () {
    alert('first textarea');
});

$("div.nicEdit-main:eq(1)").keyup(function () {
   alert('second textarea');
});
```

Comment: Thanks Clayton. That TOTALLY WORKS! I'm gonna hold off 24 hours to  give you the 'Answered' cause it seems like there should be a method within the nicEdit framework. Thanks for teaching me something new though!